# Display total number of errors with Gulp Jshint

Tags: gulp, jslint, jshint

I am trying to set up a jshint linter for the first time on my project. I am using gulp-jshint. The following config is working great I have the number of errors for each of my files. 
The question: Is that possible to have a count of all errors in the project?

ie: if fileA have 4 errors, fileB have 2 errors, fileC have 1 error
the gulp task you end up with something "Your project have 7 error in total"

Here is my gulp config

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since I posted this answer I have cleaned up and significantly expanded the code I wrote below and published it as its own package on npm: [`jshint-stylish-summary`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-stylish-summary).

Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]

---

[`jshint-stylish`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/jshint-stylish) doesn't seem to support a final summary. You might want to look for a different reporter that does what you want. (A quick [perusal of mine](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=jshint+reporter) didn't yield anything useful however.)

If you want to keep using `jshint-stylish`, you still have the option to add [a custom reporter](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint/tree/02c4053b9537d55c00c9a65ffbc6d60dbe98632d#custom-reporters). Here's one I implemented that should get you started:

```
var map = require('map-stream');

var jshintTotalReporter = function() {
  var total = { warnings: 0, errors: 0 };
  total.files = { all: 0, success: 0, warning: 0, error: 0 };
  return {
    collect: map(function(file, cb) {
      var codes = { W: 0, E: 0 };
      (file.jshint.results||[]).forEach(function(result) {
         codes[result.error.code[0]]++;
      });
      total.warnings += codes['W'];
      total.errors   += codes['E'];
      total.files.all++;
      total.files.success += (codes['W'] + codes['E'] > 0) ? 0 : 1;
      total.files.warning += (codes['W'] > 0) ? 1 : 0;
      total.files.error   += (codes['E'] > 0) ? 1 : 0;
      cb();
    }),
    report: function() {
      console.log(total.files.all + ' files checked');
      console.log(total.files.success + ' files without problems');
      console.log(total.files.warning + ' files with warnings (' +
                  total.warnings + ' warnings total)');
      console.log(total.files.error + ' files with errors (' +
                  total.errors + ' errors total)');
    }
  };
};

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  var jshintTotals = jshintTotalReporter();    
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
      .pipe(jshintTotals.collect)
      .on('end', jshintTotals.report);
});
```

(Don't forget to run `npm install --save-dev map-stream` or this won't work).

The output is rather rudimentary, but should have all the information that might be of interest. Example:

```
9 files checked
3 files without problems
6 files with warnings (13 warnings total)
4 files with errors (7 errors total)
```

If you want to pretty things up you can use [`chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) to add some color to the output and [`log-symbols`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log-symbols) for the nice little icons that `jshint-stylish` uses.